# Difference between the two sentence

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> **1** Bankers around the world have expressed deep scepticism about bitcoin, and with some reason.
>
> **2** Bankers around the world have expressed deep scepticism about bitcoin with some reason.

The first sentence is quoted from an article. I have been thinking is there any difference in meaning between the first and second one?

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a stylistic choice - there's no difference in meaning, but there is a difference in emphasis.  Presumably, the author is going to follow this sentence with a detailed discussion of the reasons why the bankers' deep skepticism is valid.  By setting off the **"and with some reason"** as its own phrase with a comma, the author draws extra attention to this phrase and implies that this is going to be the focus of further discussion.

If the author wasn't going to discuss the **reasons** for the skepticism, but just discuss the words that the bankers said or discuss other topics about bitcoin, then sentence **1** would be a poor choice and sentence **2** would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, the second passage implies that their scepticism was based on "some reason" whereas the first one looks a bit strange to me, I mean, why should one separate "with some reason" from the "main clause" putting a comma and "and" before it? It might have a stylistic reason. Concerning meaning, they seem all the same to me.